# Which overload of todictionary that I use if I do this?

Tags: vb.net

```
    Dim dict1 = fileToDict(PriceList)
    Dim dict2 = dict1.ToDictionary(Function(y) Val(y))
```

Basically I am turning dict(of string,string) to dict(of string, double).

My question is I do not see any overload of toDictionary that takes a single function of stuff.

Note: The correct format is actually

```
    Dim dict2 = dict1.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key, Function(y) Val(y.Value))
```

All of the overloaded operator takes 1 function that takes a keyvaluepair as argument.

Somehow the one that works use 2 function. That's where I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a selector for both the keys and the values.  There's no overload that is going to simply take the keys from the original `Dictionary`.  Remember that `ToDictionary` is actually called on an `IEnumerable(Of T)` so it has no idea that the source is a `Dictionary`. It only knows that it is an `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String))`.  You have to tell it how to get the keys for the new `Dictionary` from the items in the `IEnumerable(Of T)` source.

E.g.

```
Dim dict2 = dict1.ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) CDbl(kvp.Value))
```

Comment: If someone has a legitimate reason to down-vote this answer then I'd be interested to know what it is so that I can correct my error. If you're just someone with an axe to grind then I hope you enjoyed your little power trip.

Comment: Seems like an axe to grind.. This perfectly answers the question with a good explanation as to why.

Comment: I upvoted it. Actually I just want to know which overload that is used. It seems that one of the overload of todictiniory does accept 2 functions instead of 1.